# How to stop display all the record during when put blank and search,

Tags: mysql, record

i am using this search script for my website
[link](http://wikisend.com/download/653202/search.txt)

but i want to stop display all the record during when put blank and search, how to do that?. where i want to change the script?

Comment: Must we download this script to answer?

Comment: Aha, registration required... Here is wrong place for questions like this..

Comment: yes. i dont know how to past in stackoverflow. im new for stackoverflow.

Comment: Write your problem with your tried code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers